# How to serve a different home page with Express?

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to serve a different home page to the user depending if they're logged in or not?

For example, my app currently uses:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Which serves `index.html` as my home page.

Although I would like to serve `login.html` as my home page if the user is not authenticated, and `app.html` if the user is authenticated. I would do this using middleware.

Can this be done with ExpressJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach :

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        var contents, authenticated;

        // Get user is logged-in or not.
        authenticated = true/false;

        if(!authenticated) {
            contents = require('fs').readFileSync(require('path').join(__dirname, './login.html')).toString();
        }
        else {
            contents = require('fs').readFileSync(require('path').join(__dirname, './index.html')).toString();
        }
        
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.send(new Buffer(contents));
    } catch(ex) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(ex));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use app.get():

```
app.get("/", function(req,res) {
    if( userLoggedIn() ) {
        res.sendFile("/public/app.html",{ root : __dirname});
    } else {
        res.sendFile("/public/login.html",{ root : __dirname});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your line of code already set the static public directory hence everything is ready.

use `app.get('/',function(req,res){})` to map the home routing.  Perform your logic with the req object to determine weather authentication is true or false and use and send back the file of choice by `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/filename.html');`